# Homework Question: How to make Squares Recursively

Tags: python, recursion

I have a homework question that asks to make a recursive function to generate a square with side length n made of asterisks.

This is how I should implement the function: 
You’ll implement two functions in the program: the main() function, and the generate_square() function. The main function should first ask the user to enter a non-zero integer number. The latter should be called by the main() function with an appropriate argument. The ‘generate_square’ function should then generate a square (which should be represented in python by a list of strings, each terminated by a newline character) of the specified size recursively and return it to the main() function. The main function then should display the square to the user.

Here's my code.

```
def star(n):
    if n == 1:
        print('*' * n)
    if (n > 1):
        star(n - 1)

m = star(4)
```

I haven't added a main function to the body yet because I still have to fix the other function. It only prints out one asterisk and I want it to print n asterisks based on the length and width of the square.

Comment: SO 
is about fixing _your_ Code - not coding your homework. Show what code you got, where you got stuck, what the problem is and what ressources you researched to solve it (and why they did not help). Then go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Comment: The edits are getting this closer to being within site guidelines (much better than where it started!), but we're not quite there yet -- note that you can put downvotes / close votes on hold by temporarily self-deleting a question and editing while it's deleted. (If you delete it yourself you can undelete it yourself; if it's closed by vote, it takes another vote to re-open).

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/14122) is a good resource. Note the guidance to ask about a *specific* problem with your *existing* implementation -- that is to say, you should be asking about why a specific piece of what you wrote doesn't work (and providing a precise description of what "doesn't work" means in that context -- f/e, describing *exactly* what error it throws, or including real and desired outputs in the question itself to contrast them), as opposed to asking how to write some component or piece you haven't started yet.

Comment: Reading your task and looking at your code:  you should build a `list` of strings that are terminated by `'\n'` and return this `list`. You are printing directly, not building a `list`. Also: you are using recursion which is a bad choice here. You can use `c = '*' * 10` to create a string of 10 stars - use that to rewrite your `star` function without recursion and internally adding suitable strings to this list before returning the whole list to your main function.

Comment: Patrick, unfortunately, I have to build the function recursively because that's what my professor wanted to do.

Comment: Luck on your coding then. Recursivly adding to a string in python is just _bad_. Strings are immutable, you construct and throw away lots of strings that are just not needed and build up recursive stack frames of function calls - more memory spent w/o sense. Teaching students to learn bad habits - we see this far too often. if you replace the print() commands with return's and think about it your star function will work (somehow). In the n > 1 case you have to also add a * and then call star with one less n to build up the ******* you need.

Comment: @PatrickArtner well, to demonstrate the principles of recursion it's OK. Python is becoming a teaching tool in Computer Science curricula, and there are many fine curricula that will go over recursion. Indeed, I find it hard to see how you could do a proper introduction to CS without it. Anyway, aside from the stack-frames, you can generate a list of newline-terminated strings representing a square efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-recursively, one could do this rather easily, and much more efficiently:

```
def generate_square(width):
    return ['*' * width for row in range(width)]
```

However, that whole *recursive* criteria throws a whole monkey wrench into the approach, and you really have to wrap your head around the problem a different way. Still, we can take advantage of the procedural implementation to try to understand the problem better.

Using the following:

```
for w in range(1,7):
    print(f'Square of width {w}: {generate_square(w)}')
```

I get:

```
Square of width 1: ['*']
Square of width 2: ['**', '**']
Square of width 3: ['***', '***', '***']
Square of width 4: ['****', '****', '****', '****']
Square of width 5: ['*****', '*****', '*****', '*****', '*****']
Square of width 6: ['******', '******', '******', '******', '******', '******']
```

Now I can start to think about how we could derive the new square from the previous. Each time, an additional element is appended to the previous list (which is identical to any of the list's other elements), and then each element is concatenated with `'*'`. From this, we can create a general recursive specification:

```
def generate_square(width):
    # to the previous list
    prev_square = generate_square(width - 1)
    # an additional element is appended ... (which is identical to any of the list's other elements)
    prev_square.append(prev_square[0])
    # and each element is concatenated with '*'
    prev_square = [row + '*' for row in prev_square]
    return prev_square
```

However, it's still missing one rather important element of a proper recursive function: a base case. I will leave adding that as an exercise to the reader.